# How to hide error in console from manually thrown error from inside component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I need a `react-router-dom` method to throw error from component not a workaround.

How to hide error in console from manually thrown error from inside component

```
const RoleAuthOutlet: FC = () => {
    if (isLoggedIn)
        throw new Response('Not Found', { status: 404 })

    return <Outlet />
}
```

This will get caught by `errorElement` but this will log error in console

> React Router caught the following error during render

I want the error page to display `Page Not Found` while avoiding logging this error to the console.

Here is the code for the error page:

```
const ErrorPage: FC = () => {
    const error = useRouteError()

    let errorStatus: number | null = null

    if (isRouteErrorResponse(error) || error instanceof Response) {
        errorStatus = error.status
    }

    const errorMessage = errorStatus
        ? errorStatus === 404
            ? 'Page Not Found'
            : 'Something Went Wrong'
        : 'Something Went Wrong'

    return (
        <LinearGradientContainer flexDirection='column' style={{ gap: '20px' }}>
            <Title>{errorMessage}</Title>
        </LinearGradientContainer>
    )
}
```

Comment: I need to find a `react-router-dom` other  method to manually throw error from component and not a workaround.

Comment: It seems very strange to have a component that does nothing besides throw.

Comment: It has control flow check but I hide it to simplify the question

Comment: Are you basically trying to implement route protection? If a user isn't authenticated then you should render the `Navigate` component or the `navigate` function to redirect to a non-protected route. Throw error in UI is a bit irregular and odd.

Comment: I want to make the route not found if you are not allowed.